# CSS position: fixed

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I'm having difficulty fixing a problem in my html/css code for the position attribute. I want to have a word "Social" to the right and bottom with a fixed position so I can scroll with it in the same spot. I can't even get it to the right and bottom regardless of what positioning it is. Please tell me where my problem may be stemming from so I can fix it.

```html
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Template_</title>
    <!--><meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.27" /></-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
 .container{
  position:relative;
  width= 100%;
  height= 100%;
  overflow=scroll;
 }
 
 .banner{
  <!--></-->
  position:absolute;
  margin:5px;
  width:90%;
  right: 0px;
 }
 
 .banner .test{
  <!--></-->
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin:10px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
 }
 
 .banner .logo{
  <!-->controls images within banner</-->
  position: ;
 }
 .social_bar{
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 }
 #social_strip{
  <!-->post button on either left or right to remain fixed 
  through scrolling
  position:fixed;
  right:0;</-->
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
 }
 .content_container{
  <!-->contain all content within container, relative to
  overall container</-->
  position: relative;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
 }
    </style>
    </head>
    <div class="social_bar" id="social_strip">social</div>
    <body class="container">
     <div class="banner">
       <p>Banner</p>
      <div class="test">
       <p>Test</p>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content_container">
  <p>Content</p>
 </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your comments on html style. It will work.

I am not sure of this.

But in css, you need `/* */` to comment.

(e.g)

`/* This is a comment */`

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Template_</title>
    <!--><meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.27" /></-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
 .container{
  position:relative;
  width= 100%;
  height= 100%;
  overflow=scroll;
 }
 
 .banner{
  position:absolute;
  margin:5px;
  width:90%;
  right: 0px;
 }
 
 .banner .test{
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin:10px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
 }
 
 .banner .logo{
  position: ;
 }
 #social_strip{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
      width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 }
 .content_container{
  position: relative;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
 }
    </style>
    </head>
    <div class="social_bar" id="social_strip">social</div>
    <body class="container">
     <div class="banner">
       <p>Banner</p>
      <div class="test">
       <p>Test</p>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content_container">
  <p>Content</p>
 </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Correct. The CSS had malformed syntax so the `position: fixed` property was not being recognized.

Comment: @thesbros I don't remember how to comment on css. But I think his problem was the comment on the style.

Comment: thank you, it seemed to work when I did .banner .test {font-size: 3em; font-variant: small-caps;} however all the other stuff didn't. That should've been a clue but it was odd because those two worked. I'm writing my code in Geany on linux and it doesn't distinguish the /* */ as comments but it did for <!--></--> so it didn't click for me. Thank you!

Comment: @BrandonWilliams Welcome mate. See you around again.